# How to use Woocommerce in custom plugin to get cart using REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this wordpress plugin code. I need to get items in cart using a custom rest endpoint but I'm unable to load Woocommerce in my plugin. Is there something wrong in the code?

If I try to send a request using Postman I will always get this error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null`

```php
class WoocommerceRestCart {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'set_woocommerce_cart_endpoint' ) );
    }

    public function set_woocommerce_cart_endpoint()
    {
        register_rest_route( 
            'customshop', 
            '/cart', 
            array(
                'method' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_woocommerce_cart_content' ),
                'permissions_callback' => '__return_true'
            ) 
        );
    }

    public function get_woocommerce_cart_content( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        return WC()->cart->get_cart();
    }

}

new WoocommerceRestCart();
```

Comment: I don't think you can't expect `WC` to automatically exist outside of the WooCommerce context. Have you tried getting the card via the global `$woocommerce` variable, as explained here, https://usersinsights.com/woocommerce-get-cart-items/ ?

Comment: @CBroe not tried yet because on another post I've readed that the global `$woocommerce` variable is deprecated?

Comment: I can confirm that the global `$woocommerce` is deprecated, I will continue getting the error if I try like explained into the article you've linked. I've seen into the rest api that there is a rest endpoint of woocommerce that will call the cart, but if I call it will be always empty. Not sure why

Comment: _"I've seen into the rest api that there is a rest endpoint of woocommerce that will call the cart, but if I call it will be always empty. Not sure why"_ - probably due to missing context information, but it's hard to say without knowing what exact endpoint that is supposed to be, and what data it needs to get passed.

Comment: the endpoint is one of the default one of woocommerce and it's something like this `                        "href": "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/items"
`